# Медиа-запросы CSS

Tags: css3, css

Стоит задача написания медиа-запросов в CSS для подгонки столбцов сайта под широкоформатные мониторы.

Распространенная ли это практика? Всеми ли браузерами поддерживается?
И можно попросить пример, никогда с ними не сталкивался.

Вот такой пример для экрана от 1900 не сработал:

```
@media (min-width: 1900px) and (max-width: 2300px) {
    #leftCol {min-height: 1180px;}
    #contentArea {min-height: 1180px;}
    #rightCol {min-height: 1180px;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://habrahabr.ru/post/119127/

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  #pagewrap {
      width: 95%;
   }
   #content {
      width: 60%;
      padding: 3% 4%;
   }
   #sidebar {
      width: 30%;
   }
   #sidebar .widget {
      padding: 8% 7%;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
   }
}
```

Comment: Непонятно - как быть если экран больше значения 1600?

Comment: отредактировал вопрос

Comment: Полный код на jsfiddle выкладывайте. Как вы поняли, что код не сработал?

Comment: Должны были растянуться колонки таблицы при разрешении экрана больще 1600. Я проверил это в отладчике хроме

Comment: Простой пример http://jsfiddle.net/42hwnq26/1/

Хочу отметить, что медиазапрос написан в файле общем style.css

Даже такой пример не сработал

    @media all and (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width: 700px) {
        body {
            background: red;
        }
   }

Работает. Заметил такую особенность: если у боди уже задан фон, то фон из медиазапроса уже не применяется

Comment: А монитор честно 1900px поддерживает? Просто на Retina, например, по-умолчанию только 1440px и надо отдельным софтом его увеличивать. Попробовал меньшее значение - все отлично работает. http://jsfiddle.net/qLuj3rzh/ в спецификации никаких ограничений на min-width или max-width не встречал.

Comment: И еще, 1900px должна быть ширина документа в окне браузера, без скролла и границ окна.

Comment: Указывайте @media  max-width по-убыванию, а не вразброс.